# How to put object to json?

Tags: java, json

I must write one Json constructor:

```
{"userId":"wg999","personList":[{"name":"anna avocado", other fields for anna}, {"name":"bertie banana",other fields for bertie}]}
```

I have use Json object and Json array object:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
     // Set the first name/pair
        jsonObj.put("userId","MyId");

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < listArr.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject pnObj = new JSONObject();
            pnObj.put("age", listArr.get(i).Age.toString());
            pnObj.put("name", listArr.get(i).Name.toString());
            jsonArr.put(pnObj);
        }
```

and my json return:

```
{"personList":[{"name":"anna avocado", other fields for anna}, {"name":"bertie banana",other fields for bertie}],"userId":"wg999"}
```

and i don't know to write it the same with true constructor.

Thankyou so much!

Comment: Where's the problem? The order of the fields? That shouldn't matter.

Comment: you put your userId key/value pair in a jsonObj, but never uses this variable afterwards...

Comment: @Thomas Thankyou, in my case, i need true order of the field.

Comment: Well in that case you might be using the wrong JSON library. I don't know which one you're using, but the ones I know use a map inside `JSONObject` and thus the ordering is not deterministic. You'd have to do that yourself in that case.